# Powershell script for bulk action

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am in need of help making the below script import a CSV of users with their first and last names and then setting the same account expiration inside of AD using the DRA PowerShell extension. The section `"CN=User\, Test"` would be changed to `CN=$LastName\, $FirstName` and the account expiration date would need to be set to be the same for all users in the CSV file.

```
Set-DRAUser -DRARestServer draserver.na.corp.domain.com -draHostServer draserver.na.corp.domain.com -Domain na.corp.domain.com -Identifier 'CN=User\, Test,OU=Users,OU=company,OU=site,OU=city,DC=na,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=com' -IgnoreCertificateErrors -Force -Properties @{AccountExpirationDate="05/22/2022 23:59:00"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with the following code.

```
foreach ($user in $fileinput){

$name=$user -split ","

$sn=$name[0]
$fn=$name[1]

$dn="CN=$sn\,$fn,OU=Users,OU=company,OU=site,OU=city,DC=na,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=com"

$dn

Set-DRAUser -DRARestServer draserver.na.corp.domain.com -draHostServer draserver.na.corp.domain.com -Domain na.corp.domain.com -Identifier $dn -IgnoreCertificateErrors -Force -Properties @{AccountExpirationDate="05/24/2022 23:59:00"}

}
```